# Can we bend the light?

Tags: visible-light

Is there a device of method to have a source of a light beam that will bend with specific angle and distance from the source? I doubt it, but I am curious. Ofcourse without having to have a mirror at the point of the bent. Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean like [this](http://physicsed.buffalostate.edu/pubs/StudentIndepStudy/EURP09/Sugar/sugarA.jpg) ?

Comment: Fiber optics? Or do you mean something only at the original source and not located along the path?

Comment: yes, something only at the original source and not located along the path @Diracology seems nice, what is it exactly?

Comment: @ergon It is just a solution of water and sugar. It makes a liquid with a continuously changing refraction index. You can do it at home if you have a laser.